# How do I create a Start Menu folder with InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create a folder under the Start Menu using InnoSetup. On Windows 7 the start menu should show a highlight and then show my app's folder highlighted after clicking All Programs like I see when installing other apps. If I put multiple items in [icon] like below, will it automatically create a group? Or if not, how do I specify the folder?

This didn't work (taken directly from InnoIDE wizard):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
```

It only created a shortcut to the app, not a folder in the Start Menu.

Edit: It works fine on XP, but on Windows 7 I just see one shortcut when I bring up the start menu and nothing inside All Programs.

Comment: Does the extra icon appear after a restart?

Comment: Oh, and what's your `DefaultGroupName` directive set to?

Comment: Edwin, I'm seeing the same thing with a setup file I just created. I've used Inno for years and years and have compared this new setup to several that are working (and creating the start folder), and it's all exactly the same! I even used the InnoIDE Wizard to create their default setup program and it didn't work either. I'm at a loss to explain it.. Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently Windows 7 will just not show start folders after you get so many in your "all users" directory. I went to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" and deleted a few links for software I didn't use often and viola - my missing start group appeared.

Comment: Had this same issue.  It was due to having tested an install and then running the uninstall program.  When I ran the install again it did not show up in the Start Menu.  Then I logged out and logged back in and it was in the Start Menu after that.  So testing installs multiple times could cause this issue as well.  I think it is a refresh issue on the part of Windows 7 if it is not the first install.  I don't know if there is a way to fix this except for logging out and logging back in or forcing a refresh by deleting other files.

Comment: Also going to the specified folder, selecting all and removing "Read only" and "Hidden" in properties may help.

Comment: Same happened to me. Win 7 Professional x64. Wasted an hour because of this :(

Answer (score 6):

1. You're basically on the right track.   A "folder in the start menu" is indeed a "start menu group", with the InnoSetup variable "{group}".
2. Please bear in mind that Windows has two *different* start menus:

   {userstartmenu} & {commonstartmenu}
3. Here are a couple of good links (besides, of course, the actual InnoSetup documentation):

   - http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Installation_considerations
   - http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startmenuorder

PS:
Vista and Windows 7 organize shell settings and user preferences completely differently from Windows XP.  For example, "SendTo" and "Startup Folder" are now located way under

```
c:\users\SOMEUSER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.
```